# Bound on the difference of infimums

Tags: inequality, optimization, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose we have to non-negative functions $f$ and $g$ and we want to bound the difference of their infimums
\begin{align}
\left|\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}f(x)-\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}g(x)\right|
\end{align}
How can that be done?

Of course one can use triangle inequality to show that
\begin{align}
\left|\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}f(x)-\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}g(x)\right| \le \left|\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}f(x) \right|+\left|\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}g(x)\right|=\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}f(x) +\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}g(x) 
\end{align}

However, this bound is to loose.

I was wondering whether we can get a bound of the form

\begin{align}
\left|\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}f(x)-\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}g(x)\right| \le \inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|
\end{align}

If not, perhaps we can get a bound of the form

\begin{align}
\left|\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}f(x)-\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}g(x)\right| \le K\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|
\end{align}
where $K$ is some constant.

Comment: check in this articel  https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125b/ch2.pdf $\mathbb{proposition 2.18}$

Comment: @Nizar thank you. It seems we can get $|\inf f(x)-\inf g(x)| \le \sup |f(x)-g(x)|.$ Do you think we can still get the inequality of the type $\left|\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}f(x)-\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}g(x)\right| \le K\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|$

Comment: @Nizar Why $K=1$? In one we have sup in the other inf

Comment: We can't get that type of inequality, since the existence of one $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$ doesn't imply that $\inf f(x) = \inf g(x)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer so, it the inequality  $| inf f(x) -\inf g(x)| \le \sup |f(x)-g(x)|$ the tightest we can get?

Comment: @Boby I didn't  see the  $\sup$ , sorry for my mistake. By the way good that you ask so that I notice the right inequality.

Comment: No, we also have the bound $\max \{ \inf f(x),\; \inf g(x)\}$ (since our functions are non-negative), and that is often (very often) smaller than $\sup \lvert f(x) - g(x)\rvert$.